# Can not modify the comment form in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to add author, email fields to comment form but the comment form does not change. It is always showing a default template with only the comment field and submit button.

Could this be a caching issue or it is reading the comment form template from another directory?

I am using this code in my page template :

```
$comments_args = array(
  'label_submit' => __('コメント送信'),
  'title_reply' => __('コメント登録'),
  'fields' => apply_filters('comment_form_default_fields', array(
    'author' =>
    '<p class="comment-form-author">'.
    '<input id="author" class="blog-form-input" placeholder="Your Name* " name="author" type="text" value="'.esc_attr($commenter['comment_author']).
    '" size="30"'.$aria_req.
    ' /></p>',
    'email' =>
    '<p class="comment-form-email">'.
    '<input id="email" class="blog-form-input" placeholder="Your Email Address* " name="email" type="text" value="'.esc_attr($commenter['comment_author_email']).
    '" size="30"'.$aria_req.
    ' /></p>',
  )),
  'comment_notes_after' => '',
  'comment_field' => '<p class="comment-form-comment"><label for="comment">'._x('Comment', 'noun').
  '</label><br /><textarea id="comment" name="comment" aria-required="true" cols="75"></textarea></p>',
);
comment_form($comments_args);
```

Comment: Is a filter on `comment_form_default_fields` being used anywhere in your theme or in a plugin?

Comment: No other plugin or theme is using it, even if i remove  'comment_form_default_fields' , still no change on the form

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$comment_args = array( 'title_reply'=>'Got Something To Say:',

'fields' => apply_filters( 'comment_form_default_fields', array(

'author' => '<p class="comment-form-author">' . '<label for="author">' . __( 'Your Good Name' ) . '</label> ' . ( $req ? '<span>*</span>' : '' ) .

        '<input id="author" name="author" type="text" value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author'] ) . '" size="30"' . $aria_req . ' /></p>',   

    'email'  => '<p class="comment-form-email">' .

                '<label for="email">' . __( 'Your Email Please' ) . '</label> ' .

                ( $req ? '<span>*</span>' : '' ) .

                '<input id="email" name="email" type="text" value="' . esc_attr(  $commenter['comment_author_email'] ) . '" size="30"' . $aria_req . ' />'.'</p>',

    'url'    => '' ) ),

    'comment_field' => '<p>' .

                '<label for="comment">' . __( 'Let us know what you have to say:' ) . '</label>' .

                '<textarea id="comment" name="comment" cols="45" rows="8" aria-required="true"></textarea>' .

                '</p>',

    'comment_notes_after' => '',

);

comment_form($comment_args); ?>
```

May i hope this works for you

Comment: Author and email fields are still not visible. I still still see the same form with only one field (comment field) on the page .  I am expecting to see author and email fields as well

Comment: may i know which theme you used in project

Comment: how that is going to make a difference?

Comment: may be you have to override the template and then make changes in your comment form.

Comment: Where exactly needs to be overridden in template?

Comment: you can do this change on single-post.php page